# Merge multiple fbx animations into single rig

Tags: animation, armature

I have a bunch of fbx files, that contain only rig and one animation. I need to make a single file out of them, but i don't know how.

I have an idea about exporting animation data from blender from each of these files and then import it into timeline or dope sheet. But i've found no way doing this.

What can i do to have all those animations on single armature? The hierarchy is identical in each file tho.

EDIT: I've tried appending Actions from saved .blend file. It worked, but had a strange effect. Legs moved awkward. Seems like interpolation issue, but changing interpolation made completely no effect..

here is a post with gifs https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGAk.jpg

Comment: Just for reference: in case someone stumble upon this question, I have solved it with [custom python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74672/two-armature-two-rest-pose-fixing-animations)